# python analysing data csv file

Tags: python, median

I have been trying to simply the way I analyse the data for response times as it would be impossible to do it manual for each participant. However, my code does not seem to work for some reason. So basically want to look at the response times for blocks 1 to 4 with accuracy of 1 and prob_trial of 1, however my code is obviously not allowing me to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

My csv file content looks like this:

```
Block,Trial_number,Position,Probability Position,Probability State,Probability trial,Response,Accuracy,RT (ms)
1,1,N,None,None,1,N,1,976.451326394
1,2,X,None,None,1,X,1,935.360659205
1,3,M,0.9,0.81,2,M,1,936.700751889
1,4,Z,0.81,None,2,Z,1,904.942057532
1,5,X,0.9,0.81,2,X,1,952.641545009
1,6,Z,0.81,None,2,Z,1,553.098919248
```

My code is this:

```
for fnam in d_list:
    if fnam[-4:] == '.csv':

        f_in = path1 + '/' + fnam



        with open(f_in) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

            for row in reader:


                block_no.append(int(row['Block']))
                trial_no.append(int(row['Trial_number']))
                prob_trial.append(int(row['Probability trial']))
                accuracy.append(int(row['Accuracy']))
                rt.append(float(row['RT (ms)']))

           for x in block_no:
                if x < 5:f
                    for y in accuracy:
                        if y == 1:
                            for z in prob_trial:
                                if z == 1:
                                    epoch1_improbable.append(rt)

           epoch1_improbable_rt = mean(epoch1_improbable)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have the tag `median` but your code calculates the `mean` instead. Which do you want? Also, your code is not complete since you do not give us the value of `d_list`--but it is irrelevant anyway for your question. Please edit your code down to a minimal but complete example that shows your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, your description "my code is obviously not allowing me to do it" is too vague. Just what output do you want from your example input, and what are you getting now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) with which your desired result would be obtained as

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
mask = (df['Block'] < 5) & (df['Accuracy'] == 1) & (df['Probability trial'] == 1)
print(df[mask]['RT (ms)'].mean())  # 955.9059927994999
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How would you modify that to open all "data.csv" files in a folder? I.e. Data_1.csv, data_2.csv etc.

Comment: Depends on whether you want the means for each individual one, or if you want them all at once? In the former case, a loop will do. In the latter, you could merge them first and then calculate the mean. The easiest in would be to just merge as part of a loop, but it's worth noting that [Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/) makes such operations particularly straightforward.

Comment: How can I specify Blocks between 4 and 9, I tried this: df(['Block']>4 and <9) but it did not work.

Comment: Simplest would be to just do `(df['Block'] < 4) & (df['Block'] < 9)`

Comment: Thank you so much. You simplified my work quite a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer helpful, you can mark it is [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: How would you look at outliers in this case? I mean for each CSV file, I basically want it to generate z scores for the column 'RT (ms)' and then remove the ones that are above 2.5.

Comment: @CatM: In general, you're probably going to be better off by asking a new question about than rely on comment threads in older ones, but: I would `import scipy.stats as st`, `import numpy as np`, then let `z = st.zscore(df['RT (ms)'])` and `df_filtered = df[np.abs(z) < 2.5]`.